# Delphi + .Net dll deployment (on another pc)

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dll, com-interop

I develop Delphi application that uses .Net dll (written in C#) that uses another .Net dll (probably C#). 
Let me give them names A.dll and B.dll.

I have the source code of the A.dll but not B.dll.
I cannot use B.dll from Delphi app because B.dll was written only for C# applications (i.e. without COM interop) so i'm using my A.dll to work with B.dll.

B.dll creates 2 pipes to exchange messages with A.dll. The problem is that B.dll cannot(!) connect to these pipes on different computers.
However if I create A.exe instead of A.dll all is absolutely ok (pipes are connected and whole messages exchange process is ok).

On my PC I always build A.dll and Delphi app. How I understand Visual Studio automatically use commands 
1) regasm - to register A.dll,
2) tlbexp - to get A.tlb file.

After that I import A.tlb into Delphi app via "Import Type Library command".

On another computer here is the problem that in A.dll procedure pipes are never connected (I've used logs to understand this). By saying "never connected" I mean infinite waiting for the result of pipe.WaitForConnection() command (in c#).

Can anyone help me with this problem? Why "A.exe" is ok for Delphi app but not "A.dll" ?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody can help you without any real information. The reason for the lack of response is that there is no actionable detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated this problem. 
Firsly, that is bad idea to use dll inside of other dll. According to many articles there can be troubles with GetProcAddr and some other functions.
Secondly, I've developed C# app to communicate with both B.dll and Delphi app. Also, I use pipes to do this.

Comment: I think there's no reason in general to avoid A.dll calling into B.dll. If A.dll is a COM-callable wrapper (CCR), what is its threading model, i.e. MTA or STA? And does the Delphi app instantiate this COM object on a thread with the same threading model? I have seen that when the client's threading model doesn't match the server then it works on some computers but not others.

Comment: Note: in principle _there should be no failure_ with a mismatched threading model: COM handles marshalling between MTA and STA, but it will be slower. Depending on what the COM object does, it might not work, or it might crash the process.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question that you asked, and indeed make erroneous statements.

Comment: I'm sorry for late response.
I've started to program application related to COM only some days ago. In my dll I use STA model, i think, because there are no more threads. However, Delphi app uses MTA, because messages exchange process needs to be run into other thread.
It's cool that you give me such advice about need to have the same threading model, I mean for both Delphi app and A.dll.

Comment: Could you give me some links about this topic? It looks interesting enough.

Comment: David, I agree with you. I've just described the possible solution that potential developer may use to solve analogous problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use managed code from Delphi is through COM, but you don't like that way.

If your DLL targets for .NET Framework 4.x, then then you can use [DllExport](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DllExport/)

In case you are developing DLL that targets for .NET Core or .NET Standard, I recommend reading this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting

I've tried all 3 ways and they all work. The last also works well on Linux and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution from github: without COM to call .net dll from runtime.

DDNRuntime(Delphi .NET Framework/.NET Core Runtime)

https://github.com/ying32/DDNRuntime-examples

It can help you call .net fuctions easily

Just like

```pascal
function CreateMainForm(): DNForm;
var
  LButton: DNButton;
  LR: DNRectangle;
  //LEdit: DNTextBox;
begin
  LR := TDNScreen.DNClass.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

  Result := TDNForm.Create;
  Result.Text := 'Delphi .NET Runtime';

  LButton := TDNButton.Create;
  LButton.Text := 'Hello';
  LButton.add_Click(TEventClass.OnButtonClick);
  LButton.Location := TDNPoint.DNClass.init(100, 100);
  Result.Controls.Add(LButton);

  //Result.StartPosition := DNFormStartPosition.Manual;
  Result.StartPosition := DNFormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
  //Result.Location :=  TDNPoint.DNClass.init((LR.Width - Result.Width) div 2, (LR.Height - Result.Height) div 2);
end;
```